# Without using a calculator how can we say 6^20> 3.10^8?

Tags: exponentiation

Please help me understand the method you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And one more :

$6^{20}=(6^2)^{10}= (36)^{10}  > (3 \cdot 10)^{10}=$

$3^{10}10^{10} >3×10^8.$

Comment: Nice Peter, very straightforward.

Comment: Gimusi. Thanks, not so very  difficult:))

Comment: Brevity and clearness, very nice!

Answer (score 4):

$6^{20}=6^{4}6^{8}6^{8}>6^{4}2^{8}5^{8}=6^{4}10^{8}>(3)10^8$

Also, if there were meant to be parentheses:
$$6^{20}=(6^2)^{10}=36^{10}>30^{10}>30^{8}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the property of exponents: $a^{b+c}=a^{b}a^{c}$?

Comment: Yes,I am femiliar with the property sir.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$2^{10}=1024>1000=10^3$$

then

$$6^{20}=3^{20}2^{20}>2^{20}2^{20}=2^{40}=(2^{10})^4>(10^3)^4=10^{12}$$

Comment: Sir,How did this come " (10^3)^4 "?

Comment: in the first line we have shown that 2^{10}>10^3 then we can sustitute

Comment: Ok sir , now I understood.

Comment: We’ll done, Bye.

Answer (score 0):

$$6^{20}=(2\cdot3)^{20}=2^{20}\cdot 3^{20}=2^{20}\cdot {(3^5)}^4=2^{20}\cdot {243}^4\gt2^{20}\cdot {200}^4=2^{20}\cdot (2\cdot 100)^4=2^{20}\cdot 2^4\cdot 100^4=2^{24}\cdot {(10^2)}^4=2^{24}\cdot 10^8\gt3\cdot 10^8$$